# What is the equivalent of raster.setSample() in Android?

Tags: java, android, bufferedimage, raster, bitmapimage

I'm developing an app in Android that de-blurs images using the Wiener filter. Once I have done the necessary calculations with the input image (blurry image), I then need to create a new unblurred image with new values for RGBA.  I have successfully coded this in Java but cannot find a solution to the equivalent of how I create the image in Android.  I know you have to use Bitmaps in Android but cannot find how to setSample() as you cannot use BufferedImage/Raster/WritableRaster.  My code in Java is as follows,

```
final BufferedImage unblurredImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    final WritableRaster unblurredRaster = unblurredImage.getRaster();
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            unblurredRaster.setSample(x, y, 0, (rgb[x + y * width] >> 16) & 0xFF); // red
            unblurredRaster.setSample(x, y, 1, (rgb[x + y * width] >> 8) & 0xFF); // green
            unblurredRaster.setSample(x, y, 2, rgb[x + y * width] & 0xFF); // blue
            unblurredRaster.setSample(x, y, 3, (rgb[x + y*width] >> 24) & 0xFF); // alpha
        }
    }

    return unblurredImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some options, all using the `Bitmap` class:

- `setPixel(x, y, color)` where `color` is in packed int ARGB format
- `setPixels(pixels, offset, stride, x, y, width, height)` where `pixels` are in packed int ARGB format.
- `copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer)`

The last one does not convert to/from packed int ARGB format (`ARGB_8888`), so it might be the closest you get to `Raster.setSample()`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've implemented set pixel but now when I test it I seem to get a memory leak. I googled this problem and memory leaks seem to be a common problem with Bitmaps on Android. Would you know anything about dealing with Bitmap memory leaks?

Comment: I don't see why this should cause a memory leak. If you experience memory leaks, I suggest you ask a new question, and add relevant code and resources to it.